# What info will be shown on SSL certificate?

Tags: security-certificate

Say, I have my site from a host provider, during the setup of a certificate, it says that I need to fill the blank of domain name, first name, etc. What is "mandatory" to fill? If I do add personal info to the certificate, e.g. my site does not have a personal info, when filling those info when setting up a certificate, will my personal info be shown from the certificate or will it only show that the certificate is valid or verified with no personal info?

Comment: What company will the certificate be issued by?  I'd say "no, your personal info won't be displayed," but without knowing which company you're working with, it's unknowable.  Generally speaking, the personal info should only be used to contact you if there's an issue, or for promotional purposes.  Our Digicert certificate, for example, shows no personal info whatsoever, only organizational info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No. They won't show it up for normal certificates.**
There are many types of certificates. Most used and cheap are domain validation ones.
The data that they are getting from you is to identify the owner. It is for their internal use. And your info won't be shown unless you use an **Extended validation certificate**. (The one with a big green bar which holds the name of the owner). It costs more than. Usual ones.

Answer (score 1):

Generally only your company name and website address will be displayed but some higher quality SSL certificates may display your city and state and/or region.